# Trig function graphing exercise

Tags: plotting, trigonometry, homework

I am trying to figure out how to do the following exercise in Mathematica

> Graph $y(t)= a \cos t + b \sin t - 0.5 \sin t$ on the interval $0 ≤ t ≤ 6\, π$

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Plot[a Cos[t] + b Sin[t] - 0.5 Sin[t], {t, 0, 6 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {-3, 3}],
 {{a, 0}, -2, 2}, {{b, 0}, -1, 1}
 ]`

Answer (score 3):

The `Plot` function needs to have numeric values for `a` and `b`. The `With` function is a good way to supply them. Like so.

```
With[{a = -1., b = 2.},
  Plot[a Cos[t] + b Sin[t] - 0.5 Sin[t], {t, 0, 6 π},
    Ticks -> {Subdivide[0, 6 π, 6], Automatic},
    PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, @Rabbit. 'fiction` should of course be 'function'. My system's intrusive spelling corrector "fixed" a mis-typing  for me and I didn't notice it. Thanks for bringing my attention to it.

Answer (score 2):

You already got an answer. But here is another way to plot your function.

Define a function in *Mathematica* way,

```
 f[a_, b_, t_] := a Cos[t] + b Sin[t] - 0.5 Sin[t]
```

and then plot it assigning values to the parameters,

```
Plot[f[1, 1, t], {t, 0, 6 \[Pi]}]
```